# Fluxbox: Right click on window title won't open context menu

Tags: fluxbox

My fluxbox is running like a charm but unfortunately the context menu which usually pops up when clicking with the right mouse button on the window title-bar wont work. Also the same menu should show up when clicking on the entry on the fluxbox-bar.

Does anybody know that problem?

Comment: Have you got the right path of *session.screen0.windowMenu* parameter, in ~/.fluxbox/init file?

Answer (score 0):

Does the file `~/.fluxbox/windowmenu` exist?  If not, the titlebar menu will not appear.

You can generate a default windowmenu from `/usr/share/fluxbox/windowmenu`

`man fluxbox-menu` discusses this some.

If that file does exist, and its permissions are correct, then you have some other problem. But that's where I'd start.